# Ant svn revisiondiff

Tags: svn, ant, diff

Please, help me. I need to find the difference between previous version and the current version in SVN with Ant.

```
<revisiondiff
    destfile="diff.xml"
    package="ant"
    start="PREV"
    end="HEAD"
/>
```

But it doesn't work. `<svn:revisiondiff>` and `<svn revisiondiff>` do not work too. I added `svn` in path. Libraries are also connected.

Comment: Would this help? I don't see a "revisiondiff" command anywhere on Google.. This is the only thing I can find and that's either `diff` or `diffSummarize`. http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html#diff

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Are you getting an error message? If so, please include it in your question, along with the part of your script where you defined the SVN Ant tasks.